# Maya/Python - function which loops though text file except for some lines

Tags: python, maya

I've found some pieces of answers here and there but I can't figure the exact way to build what I want. Thank you by advance if you can help.

I have multiple text files, all built the same way but with different informations in each one of them. I'd like to loop over each file and return the infos in it line by line. On the other hand I have some booleans which define if one specific line in the file has to be skipped or not. For example: **"if boolean1 is true and lineInTheCorrespondingFile = 40, then skip that line, else, read it but skip line 36 and 37 instead"**.

The thing is I don't know how to proceed for the function knows which file is opened *and* which line is read *and* if the it has to skip it or not. Knowing that I need each line to be returned independently at the end of the function.

And here is my code so far:

```
def locatorsDatas (self):

    preset = cmds.optionMenu ("presetMenu", q = 1, v = 1)
    rawFile = presetsDir + preset.lower() + ".txt"

    with open(rawFile) as file:
        file.seek (0)
        for lineNum, line in enumerate(file, start = 1):
            if lineNum > 8 : # Skip header
                locator = eval (line)
                locName = locator[0]
                xVal = locator[1]
                yVal = locator[2]
                zVal = locator[3]
                locScale = locator[4]
                locColor = locator[5]
                if locator == "":
                    break

                return (locName, xVal, yVal, zVal, locScale, locColor)
```

I don't know what values I should pass into the function to make it skip the lines I want, knowing that I can't write it directly into it since each file doesn't break at the same lines.
Oh, and it only return one line of the file instead of each separately.

Hope it's clear and you can help me, thanks again.

Comment: So you have a text file you want to read some lines in and not others? And the lines you do want to read, you want to return information from it? You should be extremely careful using the `eval()` function for anything like this, by the way.

Comment: First, this is not a maya-specific question, so you'll likely get more help if you simply remove any references to it.  Just make `rawFile` an argument to `locatorsData` and cut out the `cmds` module calls.

Comment: Also, it seems like the layout of your data is a major source of the complication.  Do you have control over how the files are written?  Can you use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which support serializing data types like dicts and list?  I think it would help a lot if you could provide examples of the first few lines of the files you need to read.  Lastly, as long as the files are not extremely large, it might make more sense to merge all data into a single structure, and then extract what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of issues with your code.

To start with, you're always returning the data from line 8 and never any other data. If you have many values you want to extract from the file, you might want to make your function a generator by using a `yield` statement rather than a `return`. Then the calling code can access the data with a `for` loop or pass the generator to `list` or another function that accepts any iterable.

```
def locatorsDatas(self):
    # ...
    lineNum, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        # ...
        yield results
```

If you can't use a generator but need your function to return successive lines, you'll need to save the file iterator (or perhaps the `enumerate` iterator wrapped around it) somewhere outside the function's scope. That means you won't need to reopen the file every time the function is called. You could do something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    preset = cmds.optionMenu ("presetMenu", q = 1, v = 1)
    rawFile = presetsDir + preset.lower() + ".txt"
    self.preset_file_enumerator = enumerate(open(rawFile)) # save the iterator on self

def locatorsDatas(self):
    try:
        lineNum, line = next(self.preset_file_enumerator) # get a value from the iterator
        # do your processing
        return results
    except StopIteration:
        # do whatever is appropriate when there's no more data in the file here
        raise ValueError("no more data") # such as raising an exception
```

The next issue I see is how you're processing each line to get the separate pieces of data. You're using `eval` which is a very bad idea if the data you're processing is even slightly entrusted. That's because `eval` interprets its argument as Python code. It can do *anything*, including deleting files from your hard drive! A safer version is available as `ast.literal_eval`, which only allows the string to contain Python literals (including lists, dictionaries and sets, but not variable lookups, function calls or other more complicated code).

You also have an error check that I don't think will do what you intend. The `if locator == ""` test is probably placed too late to avoid errors from the earlier lines extracting data from the `eval`'d line. And the `break` statement you run will cause the function to exit without returning anything more. If you just want to skip blank lines, you should put the check at the top of the loop and use `continue` rather than `break`.

Now finally we can get to the issue you're asking about in the title of the question. If you want to skip certain lines based on various flags, you just need to check those flags as you're looping and do a `continue` to skip past the lines you don't want to read. I don't entirely understand what you were asking about regarding how the flags are passed, but assuming you can give them as arguments, here's a sketch of how the code could look:

```
def locatorsDatas(self, skip_40=False, skip_50=True):
    # open file, ...
    for lineNum, line in enumerate(file, start = 1):
        if  (not line or
             lineNum < 8 or
             skip_40 and lineNum == 40 or
             skip_50 and lineNum == 50):
            continue
        # parse the line
        yield result
```

Obviously you should use your own flag names and logic rather than the ones I've made up for my example code. If your logic is more complicated, you might prefer using separate `if` statements for each flag, rather than packing them all into one lone conditional like I did.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It's very helpful, I re-wrote the code my own way, as I very new to python, and everything works perfectly! :)